# How to create a client portal using WordPress, Elementor pro?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I need to create a client portal which let my clients to see their order status and other progress. We don't sell them online just need to let my customers to see updates in their dashboard and let them to download their invoices and other stuff. I need to add orders and order updates by my staff. so I can't use woocommerce. Please help tell me how to do this.

Comment: Without knowing full information about all functions and stuff. But to me it sounds like you need to build some kind of custom solution for this to work as you want. 
I don't think there is a plugin or a mixed of some plugins that will solve your problem here

Comment: @zarex360 Thank you for your reply. sorry for my bad English. I need to create one page which let users to see their orders and it's progress. when you login to your account you can see your orders and the status of them. our staff can login to page and update status for any order of any customer

Answer (score 0):

[what i am about to say is kind of a hack but...] Since what you want is not automation and you have to update every invoice manually, I think you could use acf to create a WYSIWYG field and then create a table inside it (make field condition "User->Add/Edit". Then you can update the field for each user. But keep in mind that because this field is on /profile.php you have to block users from accessing wp-admin.
To show the table in front-end you could use some plugins. Or you could use PHP (if you know how to).

I  dont know if there is any plugin for creating invoices but I think you could also use them.